# AFNetworking Upload image from iOS to API

Tags: objective-c, ios, afnetworking

I'm having trouble uploading an image with data.  This code allows me to upload data just fine:

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"my_base_url"];
AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc]initWithBaseURL:url];

//depending on what kind of response you expect.. change it if you expect XML
[client registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];

NSDictionary *params = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        _topicText.text,@"Topic",
                        @"1",@"Category",
                        @"",@"MainMedia",
                        @"1",@"Creator",
                        nil];
[client postPath:@"apidebate/debates" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    //

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"failure");
}];
```

However, I've been unsuccessful in trying to upload an image with that data:

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"my_base_url"];
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"MainMedia"], 0.5);
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/upload" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"MainMedia" fileName:@"MainMedia" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
}];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
    NSLog(@"Sent %lld of %lld bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
}];
[operation start];
```

What in the work could I be doing wrong??

**Edit** (adding server code)

The back-end is Codeigniter with the REST client Phil Sturgeon built (great library, btw).  I'm almost sure it's not the server code though, as the first line of this method sends me an email.  When I attempt to use the above code to post an image, the email never comes.  So, it seems it's nt even getting to the endpoint.

```
//CONTROLLER FROM API
function debates_post()
{
    mail('myemailaddress@gmail.com', 'Test', 'Posted');
    $tmp_dir = "images/posted/";

    if(isset($_FILES['MainMedia'])){
        $SaniFileName = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]/','', basename($_FILES['MainMedia']['name']));

        $file = $tmp_dir . $SaniFileName;
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['MainMedia']['tmp_name'], $file);
    }
    else
        $SaniFileName = NULL;

    $data = array('Topic'=>$this->post('Topic'), 'MainMedia'=>$this->post('MainMedia'), 'Category'=>$this->post('Category'), 'Creator'=>$this->post('Creator'));
    $insert = $this->debate->post_debate($this->post('Topic'), $SaniFileName, $this->post('Category'), $this->post('Creator'));
    if($insert){
        $message = $this->db->insert_id();
    }
    else{
        $message = 'Insert failed';
    }

    $this->response($message, 200);
}

//MODEL
function post_debate($Topic=NULL, $MainMedia='', $Category=NULL, $Creator=NULL){
    $MainMedia = ($MainMedia)?$MainMedia:'';
    $data = array(
                    'Topic' => $Topic,
                    'MainMedia' => $MainMedia,
                    'Category' => $Category,
                    'Creator' => $Creator,
                    'Created' => date('Y-m-d h:i:s')
                );
    return $this->db->insert('debate_table', $data);
}
```

Comment: try `[httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation]` instead of `[operation start]`

Comment: ok, so, I've done this and the result is the same:  The data seems to be uploaded by the app (I'm able to access the totalBytesWritten in the `setUploadProgressBlock`), but it never seems to hit my end point.

This is going about it the second way I have listed, trying to upload the image.  The endpoint is correct as I'm able to hit it when not trying to upload an image.  Help?

Comment: The problem seems to be on the server. Can you post the relevant server code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok, so apparently using `fileName:@"MainMedia"` for the filename left me with an extension-less uploaded file which was causing an error server-side.  Adding `".jpg"` to `"MainMedia.jpg"` fixed this.

Comment: It did help but its the first time i am doing this becoz sending extension to server side i dont think is good practise.

Comment: to add to this, when using .PNG images, only the filename is necessary.  Any other image format requires the file extension.